# Ошибка при взятии json c сервера

Tags: javascript, json

Пробую забрать json с сервера для дальнейшей манипуляции и получаю ошибку.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Нагуглил что это проблема с заголовками, пытался их поставлять разными способами 
не но выходит.

```
  var requestURL = 'http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    var obj = request.response;
    console.log(obj);
  }
```

Comment: Какими способами выславляли заголовки? Какой сервер обрабатывает запрос для http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json? Nginx? Apache? IIS?

Comment: На всякий случай... Мало ли... Заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` должен сервер www.mrsoft.by устанавливать...

Comment: Что же там такого ценного по этому [адресу](http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json)? Просто этот вопрос уже не первый на so.

Comment: можно воспользоваться публичным корс прокси

Comment: Это тестовое задание. Пытался менять на fetch('http://opendata.by/data.json', {mode: 'no-cors'}), добавлял request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/json"); Как получить этот объект. Писали о том, что во время работы страницы не надо при каждом запросе заново забирать данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер запрещает делать XHR запросы на другой домен.

Один вариант: добиться, чтобы при запросе этого файла сервер возвращал заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Например

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Другой вариант использовать прокси.
Есть публичные прокси, например этот https://jsonp.afeld.me/

```
<script>
  function myCallback(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://jsonp.afeld.me/?callback=myCallback&url=http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json"></script>
```

Либо, если есть возможность, написать простой прокси, который будет доступен на вашем домене (localhost), тогда браузер не будет ругаться.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что для этого мне потребуется реализация ajax запроса?